# CSS word wrap with floating elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed-width sidebar consisting of a bootstrap `nav-list` where some list elements have right-aligned labels.

For example:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">abc_test_randomrandom</a>
  <span class="pull-right label">0000</span>
</li>
```

However, this doesn't work if the link is long. It expands to fill the whole line, and pushes the label to the next line.

I've put up a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rouge8/gw54T/) to demonstrate this behavior. **EDIT:** And now a [gist](https://gist.github.com/4685571) too.

The desired behavior is `abc_test_randomrandom` and `0000` on the same line, with the long string wrapping to the next line if necessary. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Praveen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14633282/609144) is actually a better implementation, but to get the behavior originally requested, `display: inline-block`, `word-wrap: break-word` and setting the `width` fixes it.

```
li a {width: 70%; display: inline-block; word-wrap: break-word;}
```

[image: word wrapping]

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use a fixed width and give `overflow: hidden;` for the excess with `text-ellipsis`.

```
li a {width: 60%; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;}
li span {width: 40%; display: inline-block;}
```

I am unable to open jsFiddle. So couldn't see the exact issue.

Comment: This doesn't wrap the excess text to the next line though like they requested; it just truncates it with an ellipse...?  Also, for IE7 compatibility you need to add *display: inline; *zoom: 1; whenever you use display: inline-block since IE7 doesn't recognize that display type.

Comment: It's true that this doesn't wrap the text, but I think the ellipsis with a mouseover to expand is actually better than what I'd originally wanted.

Answer (score 2):

In Bootstrap a pull-right is essentially just a wrapper for CSS float.  You need to put the 0000 span before the abc_test_randomrandom in the markup and it should wrap the anchor to two lines as needed, so your floating element comes before the element it's floating around.  You may need to set a margin-right of the anchor to be the width of your floated element.  I can't get jsFiddle to load right now or else I'd give you a better example.  I'll try checking back.

EDIT: I was able to get your jsFiddle to load.

If you move the spans before the anchors in your HTML and add this CSS, this works.  If your text is literally going to have underscores instead of spaces then you'll need the word-wrap CSS that you mentioned in your own answer.

The benefit of this is it doesn't require CSS hacks (i.e. for display: inline-block) to work in older versions of IE, if that's a concern for your project.

```
.nav-list a { display: block; margin-right: 30px; }
```

[image: screen shot from updated jsFiddle]